# Firefox tabs flicker

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I have an issue with Firefox which makes me unable to use it. All tabs flicker. It looks like they are refreshing very rapidly. When I try to open a page in a tab, I got nothing (looks like back button is fireing and then refresh, refresh etc...).
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have acceleration enabled, a feature known to cause problems with some graphics configurations.

Open a new tab and type `about:config`. In that tab search for `layers.acceleration` and switch:

- `layers.acceleration.force-enable` to **false**.

If it's already false, try switching:

- `layers.acceleration.disabled` to **true**.

Restart your browser.

If you cannot access the `about:config` page, add these lines to the `prefs.js` file of your firefox profile:

> user_pref("layers.acceleration.force-enable", false);
>   user_pref("layers.acceleration.disabled", true);

Comment: It didn't help :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Have you tried running it with no add-ons, a clean profile or newer graphics drivers?

Comment: Not yet. But what could caused this? Tommorow morning everything were running perfectly. I just furned on my PC and I got this error.

Comment: @Paweu Could range from a firefox update or an OS update to a hardware problem. Let me know how trying the above goes.

Comment: Firefox and OS update can not be an issue because I have automatic updates disabled. I will try to do what you wrote.

How can I disable addons or make nwe profile when I can't have anything in the tab.

Comment: There is something wrong with my profile. I used MozBackup to make a backup of my profile then reinstalled Firefox then restored a profile. The issue is still present. WHen I restored the profile without "Extensions" the issue is NOT present. How can I identify which extension is causing problems?

Comment: I deleted all extensions from `\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\tq0u88tm.default\extensions`. Nothing helped except removing everything. What can I do? I do not want to lose my extensions' settings. I just want to identify that single extension (assuming it is one) that make problems.

Comment: You'll have to disable them one by one to figure out which one causes the issue.

Comment: My problem is I can't disable them because I can't do anything on FIrefox (extension manager is displayed in tab).

Comment: Backup your profile and then try moving them one-at-a-time out of `\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\tq0u88tm.default\extensions`. Or have you tried this already?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a complete fix but if you minimize the browser window and lower it by 3 centimeters from the top edge revealing your desktop background, it should stop the tabs from flickering.